# Check if value from one dataframe exists in another

Tags: r, for-loop, match

I am a beginner in R and want to know how it will works for each row.

Eg.

I have a two data frames.

I want to see if the rows exist in the other data frame. 
   I want to loop every row in ab$Fruits and check if each name is somewhere in another dataframe bc[E1:E3]columns.

```
    ab<-data.frame(Fruits = c("Apple","Banana"),Units = c("3","2"))

    bc<-data.frame("E1"=c("Apple","Grapes","Watermelon","Na"),
                   "E2"=c("Grapes","Berries","Custard","Guava"),
                   "E3"=c("Apple","Banana","Grapes","Na"))
```

eg.

When the loops starts, first row of ab$fruits match with each column of bc,if first row (Apple) match with bc$E1 ,in ab$new column the result should return 1 and loop breaks.Again 2nd row (Banana) search for each column in bc,if it is not match with any in column bc$E1 ,in ab$new column result should return 0.

Again loop iterates.

When ab$fruits(apple) loop reach from row 1 (Apple) and match with column bc$E3 also row 2 (Banana) matches with Banana the result should be ab$new = 1 for both the rows.

IF ab$new for both the rows ==1 and sum of both the units is >=5 ,create new column in ab$view = "Bill"
  output  ab:

```
**SN Fruits     Number New** view
1  Apple       3        1    Bill
2  Banana      2        1    Bill
```

I have tried %in% but not happening.

Need advice.

Comment: Where did strawberry come from? Please try and be more clear with your explanations. Also please show what you have tried

Comment: What does "in the same column/group" mean? Does the `ab` column `SN` and the `bc` column `Fruit` have something to do with that? (I.e., by "same column/group" do you mean "same row number"?) Is strawberry a typo? It appears from nowhere in the results?

Comment: you can do `ab$New <- ab$Fruits %in% as.matrix(bc[-1])` or `as.integer(ab$Fruits %in% as.matrix(bc[-1]))`

Comment: Tried it how? Please be more specific about the problem than "not happening"

Comment: Guyss ....given edited and clear explanations....Tried with for loop function but unable to go further as new in R

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unlist` and optional also `unique` and use `%in%` to check if *Fruits* are there.

```
ab$New <- +(ab$Fruits %in% unique(unlist(bc[-1])))
if(all(ab$New == 1) && sum(as.numeric(as.character(ab$Units))) >= 5) ab$view <- "Bill"
ab
#  Fruits Units New view
#1  Apple     3   1 Bill
#2 Banana     2   1 Bill
```